Different column width of first column of \cventry within document (per section)
I use the article class for my CV and \cventry for the column entries.
Is there a way to renew the command per section of how many entrys a single \cventry has, how wide the first column is supposed to be and if bold or not etc.? (see image below)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[
a4paper, 
left=3.5cm,
right=3.5cm,
top=4cm,
bottom=4cm
]{geometry}

\newcommand\cventry[3]{
    \par\medskip\noindent
    \parbox[t]{3cm}{\bfseries#1}
    \hspace*{1em}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-1em}
        {\bfseries#2}
        \def\tmp{#3}
        \ifx\tmp\empty\else
        \\#3
        \fi
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}\Large
        {Name Surname}\\
        
        {\normalsize Adress}\\
        \vspace{-2mm}
        {\normalsize Phone}\\
        \vspace{-2mm}
        {\small Email}
    \end{center}
    
    \section*{Education}
    \cventry{2013 – 2014}{University4, City}{Studies}
    \cventry{2012 – 2013}{University3, City}{Studies}
    \cventry{2011 – 2012}{University2, City}{Studies}
    \cventry{2010 – 2011}{University1, City}{Studies}
    
    \section*{Some other skills}
    
    \cventry{I need this column to be wider} {This should not be bold}

\end{document}


